# Selenium driver does not reflect page changes after click()

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The source returned by the following code does not reflect changes in the web page caused by a javascript after calling click(). What am I missing?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click(); // changes page content
Thread.sleep(10000);
String src = driver.getPageSource(); // src does not reflect changes
```

Comment: What you are trying to perform? , Does it changing page when you click using xpath?

Comment: The page does change when I click the xpath. I'm trying to catch some of the text that is displayed on the page after the change.

Comment: then it should catch changed data ,  also you can find that text area and you can use Gettext() method to catch texts.

Comment: Yup, indeed it should. Strangely, when I print the source as above, nothing has changed.

Comment: Please try with other browser..:)

Comment: I've tried Safari and Firefox so far.

Comment: if possible then share site URL where you are trying.

Comment: I have found that the most reliable way to execute Javascript on a page is by sending a TAB key. In Java you can do: `driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.TAB);`

Answer (score 4):

You should not rely on webdrivers `getPageSource()` method.

From the docs:

> getPageSource
>
> java.lang.String getPageSource()
>
> Get the source of the last loaded page. If the page has been modified
>   after loading (for example, by Javascript) there is no guarantee that
>   the returned text is that of the modified page. Please consult the
>   documentation of the particular driver being used to determine whether
>   the returned text reflects the current state of the page or the text
>   last sent by the web server. The page source returned is a
>   representation of the underlying DOM: do not expect it to be formatted
>   or escaped in the same way as the response sent from the web server.
>   Think of it as an artist's impression.
>
> Returns: The source of the current page

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource%28%29

Comment: Ah, mystery solved it seems. Seems I have to dig deeper into the driver docs. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, for the reasons described on the javadocs (that there is no guarantee that the returned text is that of the modified page... Think of it as an artist's impression)